# Ruby on Rails - Creating a route for a custom view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, rails-routing, custom-routes

I feel like I'm really close so I'll get to the point. I've created a new view file (app/views/subjects/screening.html.erb). That would place the new file next to the edit.html.erb, which I used as my template. My edit.html.erb file works as intended, which is really weird because I've copied the logic/routes/etc for my new file, and I'm not getting the same results.

This is frustrating. The MVC is being mean.

So here is the link to the page:

subjects/index.html.erb

```
  <% @subjects.each do |sub| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to "edit", edit_subject_path(sub) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "scr", screening_path(sub) %></td>
      <td><%= sub.subject_id %></td>
      <td><%= sub.study_site == 1? "Seattle" : sub.study_site == 2? "Portland" : "nil"%></td>
      <td><%= sub.treatment_group %></td>
    </tr> 
  <% end %>
```

Where the link to "edit" works, producing this URL 'localhost:3000/subjects/{:id}/edit'. And the link to "scr" does not, producing 'localhost:3000/screening.{:id}'.

routes.rb

```
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  # resources :subjects, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :subjects



  match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  match '/edit', to: 'users#edit'

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

  match '/subjects', to: 'subjects#show'
  match '/newsubject', to: 'subjects#new'
  match '/subjects', to: 'subjects#index'
  match '/showsubject', to: 'subjects#show'
  match '/editsubject', to: 'subjects#edit'
  match '/screening', to: 'subjects#screening'
```

Do I have to declare something extra because I added it manually? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a nested route like so:

```
resources :subjects do 
  match '/screening', to: 'subjects#screening', as: :screening
end
```

Which should allow:

```
link_to "scr", subject_screening_path(sub)
#> /subjects/1/screening
```

I could be a little off with the naming. Be sure to check your routes (`rake routes` in shell). Also, remove:

```
  match '/subjects', to: 'subjects#show'
  match '/newsubject', to: 'subjects#new'
  match '/subjects', to: 'subjects#index'
  match '/showsubject', to: 'subjects#show'
  match '/editsubject', to: 'subjects#edit'
  match '/screening', to: 'subjects#screening'
```

These routes are automatically generated with `resources :subjects`, though by default their paths differ.

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I try to load the index page, I get 'Undefined method "screening_subject_path(sub)"'. I'm playing with the naming convention, but so far I haven't found a way to get it to work. Also, thanks for the tip about the other routes.

Comment: @IanEllis you need to run `rake routes` to determine the exact name of that route. It might be `subject_screening_path`. I always get mixed up with nested routes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That was the problem. I'm just starting to get the hang of these routes.

Comment: @IanEllis great to hear!